# SQL query to group by consecutive time

Tags: mysql, sql

With the following sample data, I am trying to group these records into three groups given a 'break' time.

| ID | Lat | Lng | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 01:00:00 |
| 2 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 01:01:00 |
| 3 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 01:02:00 |
| 4 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 01:03:00 |
| 5 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 01:04:00 |
| 6 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 01:15:00 |
| 7 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 01:16:00 |
| 8 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 01:17:00 |
| 9 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 01:18:00 |
| 10 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 02:10:00 |
| 11 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 02:11:00 |
| 12 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 02:12:00 |
| 13 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 02:13:00 |
| 14 | 80.1 | -120.2 | 2021-03-01 02:14:00 |

So given an idle interval of 5 minutes or more,  how could I group these records into 3 groups? The first group would be records 1-5, the second group would be records 6 - 9, and the third group would be records 10 - 14, because there is a break of over 5 minutes between records 5 and 6, and 9 and 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum( case when prev_timestamp < timestamp - interval 5 minute or
                      prev_timestamp <> prev_timestamp_ll
                 then 1
                 else 0
            end ) over (order by timestamp) as grp           
from (select t.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by lat, lng order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp_ll,
             lag(timestamp) over (order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aea4603a50e29ad72503f43e754570be) is a db<>fiddle.